# Which type of diagram do I use to represent the 'Information View' of system modules/components?

Tags: uml, diagram, diagramming

I would like to represent the system as a collection of modules (structural diagram) with each module declaring the information it owns and the information it requires for its operation. The relationship between the modules will be derived from the declarations itself (i.e. connect module which requires information with the modules that owns the required information).

The information elements will be classified on the basis of 3 criteria -

1. Information classified according to nature -

   - Static - Known prior execution and remains unchanged during execution
   - Dynamic - Likely to change during execution
2. Information classified according to ownership -

   - Owned - Module owns this information
   - Required - Module requires this information to function
3. Owned information is classified according to visibility -

   - Public - Externally Visible
   - Internal - Not visible externally

The closest fit I could find were (but not exactly 'it') -

- Composite Structure diagram (UML)
- Package diagram (UML)
- Component diagram (UML)
- Block Definition Diagram/Internal Block diagram (SysML)

Comment: Your diagram selection seems fine and according to [UML 2.5 Diagrams Overview](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/uml-25-diagrams.html) "_..UML specification does not preclude **mixing** of different kinds of diagrams.._". So your question is how to represent the 6 different "information element classifiers"? Can you give us **some concrete** class or package **names and relationships** you need to represent?